# How to add units in a column of numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am wondering if there is a way to add unit (m,ft etc) in a column of numbers in a attribute table in QGIS.  I want to do this so when I post the text the units can be posted as well. I am working with pressure data so i would like to the Kpa after the number.

Comment: Please do not post questions with ALL CAPS titles.  In addition to being more difficult to read, doing so will encourage downvotes.  Is there a reason you can't add a units column to the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't store UoM (units of measure) in a numerical field. UoM is text, which is not compatible with the numerical format. It's common practice to include the UoM in the field title, eg instead of calling a field "Area" call it "Area_ac" (for acres), "Area_ha" (for hectares) or "Area_sqm" (for square meters).

If you want the UoM stored in each field, you can create a new field in text(string) format, and copy over the values from the original column. Because this is a text field storing mixed numbers and text values, you won't be able to do mathematical functions, not even with the `to_int()` function to convert a string to an integer.

If you simply want to *display* the numerical field with UoM, say as a label, you can use the expression builder to add UoM to the label. Eg, with a field called "Area_sqm", label with this expression:

```
"Area_sqm" || ' sq m'
```

or this:

```
concat("Area_sqm", ' sq m')
```

Comment: Or, even shorter `"column-name"||' unit'`

Comment: *face palm* I'm too used to concatenating multiple columns...

Comment: Don't worry, my first model from a year ago is a leviathan of unnecessary `concat`. Also, basically your original solution was both right and more easily understandable.

Comment: If I successfully answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. This helps other users know that this answer was useful.